ASP.Net MVC - TypeError $(...)camera is not a function
I am trying to get Camera slideshow to work in an ASP.Net MVC view. I have successfully got it working in a normal HTML environment. It is called 'camera wrap'.
I am using version 5.2.9.0 of MVC in Visual Studio 2022. I've been working with VB.Net for a long time but I am relatively new to the use of HTML, CSS and Javascript. I understand their interaction and what they do. I particularly want to use MVC (VB.Net).
I literally copied a working HTML doc into my MVC view. I have added the relevant css, javascript and images to the solution. The HTML includes the relative references to the scripts and css file. I have also tried loading them all using the 'bundles' option. I have also changed the $ sign for 'jQuery' in the function call. The script for this is...
    <script>
        jQuery(function () {

            jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
                thumbnails: true
            });

            jQuery('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
                height: '400px',
                loader: 'bar',
                pagination: false,
                thumbnails: true
            });
        });
    </script>

I get the following error...
TyepError
with this stack trace error.
stacktrace
I'm hoping this is something that is due to my lack of MVC knowledge, I have tried unsuccessfully to search for this issue in various locations.
This is the HTML I copied...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Camera is a Pixedelic free jQuery slideshow | Manuel Masia (designer and developer) --> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" > 
    <title>Camera | a free jQuery slideshow by Pixedelic</title> 
    <meta name="description" content="Camera a free jQuery slideshow with many effects, transitions, adaptive layout, easy to customize, using canvas and mobile ready"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    //      Styles
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////--> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='camera-css'  href='../css/camera.css' type='text/css' media='all'> 
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        a {
            color: #09f;
        }
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #back_to_camera {
            clear: both;
            display: block;
            height: 80px;
            line-height: 40px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .fluid_container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 1000px;
            width: 90%;
        }
    </style>

    <!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    //      Scripts
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////--> 
    
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../scripts/camera.min.js'></script> 
    
    <script>
        $(function(){
            
            $('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
                thumbnails: true
            });

            $('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
                height: '400px',
                loader: 'bar',
                pagination: false,
                thumbnails: true
            });
        });
    </script>
 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="back_to_camera">
        <a href="http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/">&larr; Back to the Camera project</a>
    </div><!-- #back_to_camera -->
    
    <div class="fluid_container">
        <p>Pagination circles with the height relative to the width</p>
        <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/bridge.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/bridge.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Camera is a responsive/adaptive slideshow. <em>Try to resize the browser window</em>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/leaf.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/leaf.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    It uses a light version of jQuery mobile, <em>navigate the slides by swiping with your fingers</em>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/road.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/road.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    <em>It's completely free</em> (even if a donation is appreciated)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/sea.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/sea.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Camera slideshow provides many options <em>to customize your project</em> as more as possible
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/shelter.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/shelter.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    It supports captions, HTML elements and videos and <em>it's validated in HTML5</em> (<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pixedelic.com%2Fplugins%2Fcamera%2F&amp;charset=%28detect+automatically%29&amp;doctype=Inline&amp;group=0&amp;user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2" target="_blank">have a look</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/tree.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/tree.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Different color skins and layouts available, <em>fullscreen ready too</em>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- #camera_wrap_1 -->

        <p>Thumbnails with fixed height</p>
        <div class="camera_wrap camera_magenta_skin" id="camera_wrap_2">
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/bridge.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/bridge.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Camera is a responsive/adaptive slideshow. <em>Try to resize the browser window</em>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/leaf.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/leaf.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    It uses a light version of jQuery mobile, <em>navigate the slides by swiping with your fingers</em>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/road.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/road.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    <em>It's completely free</em> (even if a donation is appreciated)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/sea.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/sea.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Camera slideshow provides many options <em>to customize your project</em> as more as possible
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/shelter.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/shelter.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    It supports captions, HTML elements and videos and <em>it's validated in HTML5</em> (<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pixedelic.com%2Fplugins%2Fcamera%2F&amp;charset=%28detect+automatically%29&amp;doctype=Inline&amp;group=0&amp;user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2" target="_blank">have a look</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/slides/thumbs/tree.jpg" data-src="../images/slides/tree.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Different color skins and layouts available, <em>fullscreen ready too</em>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- #camera_wrap_2 -->
    </div><!-- .fluid_container -->
    
    <div style="clear:both; display:block; height:100px"></div>
</body> 
</html>

One point, the 'camera' function is in another script - camera.min.js not jquery.min.js as noted in the stack trace???
I have tried loading the sripts and css file using the 'bundles' option. I have 'dragged' the scripts + css references into the view from the solution explorer.
I have changed the $ sign for 'jQuery'. One point, the 'camera' function is in another script - camera.min.js not jquery.min.js as noted in the stack trace???

It works fine outside of MVC
